# Angular 15 TypeError: Cannot assign to readonly property only exist in dev mode

Tags: angular, typescript

I confront an error cause by assign a property to value from ngrx state, but this error only show in dev environment.

Could anyone help explain why this error not show in production mode ?

Here's my tsconfig.json and angular.json :

angular.json:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/assets"],
            "styles": ...,
            "scripts": ...,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom", "es2019.array"],
    "paths": ...,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "strict": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I tried to change the builder of angular and also try to add strict mode in development mode, but this error still exist in development only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer from @MarianTheisen:

NgRx will automatically disable run time checks in production builds.

Answer (score 0):

First Check for Immutable Objects in your code:

Do Ensure that you are not trying to modify an object or property that is intended to be immutable. When it comes to Angular, it's a good practice to work with immutable data structures, and if you need to make changes, create a new object with the updated values.

Seocondly, Since you have mentioned the error message that is "only exists in dev mode." It's possible that there might be some development-only code or behavior that is causing the issue. Check your code for any development-specific configurations or features that might be affecting this.

Check for the below Incorrect  occurrences of the code:

```
// Incorrect way (mutating the object)
this.myObject.property = newValue; // This can cause the readonly error
```

Correct way of doing :

```
// Correct way (creating a new object with the updated value)
this.myObject = { ...this.myObject, property: newValue };
```

Comment: I think ngrx has a dev mode check for immutability. see https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#:~:text=The%20number%20one%20rule%20of,possible%20to%20recreate%20the%20state . this is extremely important to follow in ngrx. OP should fix his code.

Comment: @MarianTheisen That's the answer I found, thanks!